# How to set to collapse other div item when other one is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried through various method but didn't work. What I'm trying is to open only one div at time please open the above link to check
please suggest any alternate or suggestion

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gm2k3ewp/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group row" id="accordion">
    <div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>
        </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="col-md-3 panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="col-md-3 panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="col-md-3 panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `Javascript` code:

```
$('#accordion a').click( function(e) {
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

It will add listener to the `click` event of the links elements, and will collapse all before opening the clicked item.

Comment: Thank You So Much Its Worked

Comment: Sorry @KrishnaChaitanyaKollu, I also contribute with the portugues SO community and answered the question in portuguese. Fixed up :)

Answer (score 0):

use this fiddle

In here i have added panel default class.

> ```
> 'http://jsfiddle.net/gm2k3ewp/1/'
> ```